# Prompt user to enter names and prints out the list in python

Tags: python, list, append, prompt

trying to make a program that prompts user to enter a famous peoples names and continues asking until they type "done" and prints out the list with the names and the number of names. could anyone give me a little help?

```
def main():
    cList = []
    cName = []
    while cName != ("done"):
        cList.append(cName)
        cName = input("Enter another name: ")
    print("# of names entered: "), [cList]
    i = 0
    while i < len(cList):
        print myList[i]
        i += 1
    return

main()
```

Comment: Why are you starting `cName = []`? Do you really want to append an empty list to the start of the list of names? Why are you printing `[cList]`—that is, a list of one item containing the list of names? Where's the closing parens on your first `print`? What is that `i = 0` supposed to be indented under? Is this Python 2, where you're almost certainly misusing `input`, or Python 3, where that second `print` is a SyntaxError? Without knowing what each line of your code is intended to do, it's hard to help you fix them.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mateo. Ask a more specific question about your program to get better help. What are you stuck with, exactly?

Comment: Thank you @alexis but basically i have no idea what i am doing. i think i am doing my assignment right i've been doing a lot of research and got the basics of it. but i get errors and nothing seems to be right. it gets so frustrating

Comment: @Mateo: "I get errors" is not a question. "Why do I get an `IndentationError` on line 2?" is a question. If you copy and paste the complete traceback, and explain why you think it's valid as written, and where you've looked for more information, then it's not just a question but a _good_ question.

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morpheus\Downloads\celebrities-2.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Morpheus\Downloads\celebrities-2.py", line 30, in main
    while i < len(cList):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment'

Comment: Edit your question and paste the error into it. Also, please fix the formatting so that all of the code shows up as code, and is indented the same way as your real code (especially important in cases like this, where the indentation may be the actual problem).

Comment: Meanwhile, it looks like you may be mixing tabs and spaces in your source code. Never, ever do that. It causes Python to think your code is indented differently from the way it looks to you. Try running with the `-t` flag to verify that you're being consistent. And, if you're using an editor that doesn't make it easy to be consistent, switch editors.

Comment: @abarnert i cant seem to change the text to the code format..i feel so dumb.

'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment' that seems to be the first error

Comment: Again, don't paste errors in comments, edit them into the question.

Comment: What is the mysterious `myList` in the `while` loop at the end of your program which is _supposed_ to print the names? Should that be `cList`? Also, you should change that `while` loop into a `for` loop. See the loop at the end of brunsgaard's code below.

Comment: @Mateo, getting started with coding can be very frustrating. The best way is to have someone sit next to you who can help you get off the ground. (Your teacher, a TA, a friend or fellow student who is further along). If you get the answer handed to you here, you're not going to be any wiser about what was going wrong. Don't beat your head against the wall, find someone who can spot the *simple* things that must be going wrong-- and this is best done in person at this stage. Once you know what to pay attention to, it'll get easier.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
names = []
while True:
    names.append(raw_input('Enter name: '))
    if names[-1] == 'done':
        names.pop()
        break
print("# of names %i" % len(names))
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: This doesn't gather the names into a list that he can print out, and print the length of.